# Property set method without private variable

Tags: c#, properties, accessor

I got the simplest property like

```
public bool Something { get; set; }
```

But in almost every one of them I need to call some method after set, so one line became

```
private bool _something;
public bool Something {
    get{ 
        return _something;
    }
    set{
        _something = value;
        CallMethod();
    }
}
```

But it's broke all visual side of code. 
So my question is if I can call setter method and stay with clear code?

Comment: that looks fine. anything else you do would just add complexity. beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: What are you _doing_ in `CallMethod`?  You might look at some aspect-oriented programming libraries so see if they support automatic properties.

Comment: Whatever `CallMethod` do... In next version of C# they should do
`public bool Something { get; set{ CallMethod(); } }`

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, the simple answer is no. When you create your property with just a get and set, it's referred to as an auto-property. The compiler still creates the full code with the backing private variable.

What you have would be considered standard coding practice. It's a few extra lines of code, but easily readable.